# Does ApiGen 5 support multiple file extensions?

Tags: php, apigen

I am using ApiGen 5.0.0-RC3, and I cannot figure out how to get it to search for `.class` files and `.inc` files as well as `.php` files.

My question is twofold: firstly, is it possible to get ApiGen to recognize `.class` files, and secondly, if it is possible, how would one go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way... but it's pretty hacky. I'm posting it here in the hopes that it might be able to help someone else.

The solution is not actually in ApiGen, but in [roave/better-reflection](https://github.com/Roave/BetterReflection). Specifically, in the file `src/SourceLocator/Type/FileIteratorSourceLocator.php`, in the method `getAggregatedSourceLocator`, in an anonymous function.

Replace:

```
private function getAggregatedSourceLocator() : AggregateSourceLocator
{
    return $this->aggregateSourceLocator ?: new AggregateSourceLocator(array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        function (\SplFileInfo $item) : ?SingleFileSourceLocator {
-            if (! ($item->isFile() && pathinfo($item->getRealPath(), \PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'php')) {
                 return null;
             }
            return new SingleFileSourceLocator($item->getRealPath());
        },
        iterator_to_array($this->fileSystemIterator)
    ))));
}
```

With:

```
private function getAggregatedSourceLocator() : AggregateSourceLocator
{
    return $this->aggregateSourceLocator ?: new AggregateSourceLocator(array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        function (\SplFileInfo $item) : ?SingleFileSourceLocator {
+            $flag = in_array(pathinfo($item->getRealPath(), \PATHINFO_EXTENSION), ['php', 'class']);
+            if (! ($item->isFile() && $flag)) {
                 return null;
             }
            return new SingleFileSourceLocator($item->getRealPath());
        },
        iterator_to_array($this->fileSystemIterator)
    ))));
}
```

Works as of commit 47b76f7, version *something*